# SonarQube C# Runner and Visual Studio report different CA results

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, code-analysis, tfs-2015

I am trying to setup SonarQube to report on our C# projects. I have created a new Quality Profile in SQ which only include the Code Analysis rules (225 in total). I have made sure that these rules are in sync with the projects in source in Visual Studio.

When SonarQube analysis is run, different results are reported. Visual Studio tends to pick up more than the SonarQube runner.

For example, here are 3 results from SonarQube about rule CA1704:

[image]

and for the same solution in VS, there are many more:

[image]

The 3 that I have highlighted are the 3 that SonarQube is picking up.

This is the same for a number of different rules. I want SQ and VS to report the same results. I run analysis on TFS build (vNext), can I simply pass the results from the build to SonarQube? I mean, if I don't have to run it twice then great.

Do I need to modify the SonarQube rules themselves? Has anyone experienced this problem before?

**UPDATE**

I have enable verbose logging on the sonar publish and I have found that it is skipping some issues found:

```
2016-01-08T14:33:53.5086817Z 14:33:53.430 DEBUG - Skipping the FxCop issue at line 10 which has no associated file.
2016-01-08T14:33:53.5243155Z 14:33:53.430 DEBUG - Skipping the FxCop issue at line 19 which has no associated file.
```

There are lots of these for every project in my solution and the gap matches exactly, e.g. in the above case, VS reports 47 issues but SonarQube reports 45. I cannot yet find a correlation and Google doesn't have much info on it. This is going to be a big problem as one of my solutions has 18.5k issues but SonarQube is only reporting 13k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the CA1704 violations that aren't showing up in SonarQube for classes or for members that are declared as fields, as opposed to properties?  If so, you've run into one of the more "interesting" behaviours of the FxCop plug-in for SonarQube, which is that it ignores any violations that do not include a file and line number (see the relevant source file at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-fxcop-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/fxcop/FxCopSensor.java, of which current version is [c518065](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-fxcop-library/commit/c518065de80bb9bd537ac4c0f6d9681e7860ea99) for the details if you're interested).

Line numbers in FxCop reports are taken from the PDB for the target assembly.  However, the PDB only contains lines for executable code, so violations that aren't associated with executable lines of code (or at least with a method that FxCop can tie to its first line) won't have a file name or line number in the FxCop report.  These will all end up getting ignored by SonarQube.

If you're dependent on SonarQube reporting of your FxCop results, you may wish to consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. In my example in the pics above, the ones it has missed are public enums. I've been through a few other projects and it's missing members and class names for example. That's annoying but at least I know what it is now. Thanks